# How to get more than 20 tweets with Bluemix Twitter Insights?

Tags: ajax, node.js, api, twitter, ibm-cloud

I'm using [this code](https://hub.jazz.net/project/kungr/sample-cdetestapp/overview?utm_source=dw&utm_medium=article&utm_content=cl-twitter-search-insights-bluemix-trs&utm_campaign=bluemix) to create a Twitter Insight app in Bluemix. However, I can't find any documentation on how to increase the number of tweets retrieved by the API. I tried using size and count as parameter in the query but without result. Is it possible to get more tweets?

```
    $.ajax({
        url:'/api/search/',
        type: 'GET',
        contentType:'application/json',
        data: {
            q: term,
            size: 100
        },
        success: function(data) {
            // do stuff
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
            // do error stuff
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server side code you are using has a hard coded value of 20 for the number of tweets returned in the `app.js` file:

```
var MAX_TWEETS = 20;

// callback - done(err, data)
function insightRequest(path, query, done) {
    request({
        method: "GET",
        url: insight_host + '/api/v1/messages' + path,
        qs: {
            q: query,
            size: MAX_TWEETS
        }
    }, function(err, response, data) {
```

You have to modify that value for the max number you want to return, or make a parameter you can pass to function.